I need to redirect Anonymous user to login page
I have a webform that is restricted to Authenticated user. The form is working as intended. When Anonymous user try I access the form they get The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later. . I want Anonymous user to be directed to the login page so I installed Redirect 403 to User Login https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login but it did not make a difference . I changed the setting >> Form >> Form access denied settings and still none of the option made a difference .
I am getting the following message in the log : Drupal\Core\Http\Exception\CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException: in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess()
Appreciate any help or thoughts
Edit:
Drupal 10
Access is restricted through the webform by unchecking the Anonymous user

Not sure if it helps but I am also getting this error:
Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent::getException() in Drupal\url_redirect\EventSubscriber\RedirectSubscriber->exceptionRedirect() (line 116 of /var/www/drupal/modules/contrib/url_redirect/src/EventSubscriber/RedirectSubscriber.php)

#0 [internal function]: Drupal\url_redirect\EventSubscriber\RedirectSubscriber->exceptionRedirect()
#1 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): call_user_func()
#2 /var/www/drupal/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(239): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch()
#3 /var/www/drupal/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(91): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleThrowable()
#4 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
#5 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle()
#6 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ContentLength.php(28): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle()
#7 /var/www/drupal/core/modules/big_pipe/src/StackMiddleware/ContentLength.php(32): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle()
#8 /var/www/drupal/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(191): Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle()
#9 /var/www/drupal/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(128): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch()
#10 /var/www/drupal/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(82): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup()
#11 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle()
#12 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle()
#13 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/AjaxPageState.php(36): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle()
#14 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/StackedHttpKernel.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle()
#15 /var/www/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(704): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle()
#16 /var/www/drupal/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle()
#17 {main}


How have you restricted the webform to authenciated users? Sounds like something is broken there and until that's fixed it's unlikely any redirection you add is going to work

Webform >> Settings >> Access >> Uncheck  Anonymous user in Create submissions section

“ The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.” is not a 403 error, which is why the 404 redirect model isn’t working for you.

https://www.drupal.org/project/url_redirect is the module causing the problem. Uninstall it.

thank you @monalisa for your help . This is what I did and it fixed the problem . For some reason the Moderator deleted my answer?
